# jCarousel (jQuery Carousel): last item not showing properly in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, jcarousel

I've set up a test page here: http://benjavita.org.uk/tests/carousel.html

It seems like adding icon images causes a problem for the last item in IE7, as it displays on 2 lines (Firefox and IE8 are ok).

Any suggestions are welcome!

Thanks, Ben

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a quick and dirty fix:

Try adding an extra list-item in the end, with the same class as the others, but leave the span blank.